# Trying to get the percentage of rows rowwise for a particular condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have obtained a dataframe of 39 rows.

```
    col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4  col5
0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   0   0   0   0   0   
2   56  57  24  56  0
```

What percentage of rows are with 30+ value among all
the rows available in a dataframe?

This is the data.I have to split it into different columns.

13                                           [000, 000]

14    [XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, ...

15        [000, 000, 000, 000, DDD, 000, 000, 000, 000]

16                                           [000, 000]

17                                 [000, 000, 000, XXX]

18    [000, 077, 046, DDD, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, ...

19    [000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, ...

20                            [000, 052, 000, 000, XXX]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) to compare your values, and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to count the `True` values:

```
df.gt(30).sum(axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    3
dtype: int64
```

For the percentage use [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and multiply by 100:

```
df.gt(30).mean(axis=1).mul(100)
```

output:

```
0     0.0
1     0.0
2    50.0
dtype: float64
```

If you want the output to be a `DataFrame`, add [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df.gt(30).sum(axis=1).to_frame(name='count')
```

output:

```
   count
0      0
1      0
2      3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.My dataframe consist of one column which consist of list of rows. For example [000,000,000,000]\n[000,52]\n[099,002]. They are not even of same length. how to split it.

Comment: i have used pd.series but its giving lots of rows. any other idea ?

Comment: please provide the output of `df.to_dict()` for reproducibility as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74065407/edit) to your question

Comment: df['col'].apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).Is there is any other way

Comment: Can you provide your example data in a reproducible format?

Comment: No i am not able to.Its same as given in 1st answer [000,000,000,000]\n[000,52]\n[099,002]

Comment: `000` is not a valid python number, do you have strings? What prevents you from providing a reproducible input?

Comment: i have updated the problem.Kindly see above